# How to Codeigniter HMVC Callback function error on live server?

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

A**Good morning all.**

I have build a website in codeigniter3 hmvc. all routes and callback function work perfectly on my localhost xampp and after uploading the project on godday share hosting live server I am facing callback funciton problems and below errors show in log file I don't understand why this happen. my user logging function also show this error:-

**Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(verifylogin)**

Error Logs in logs folder of codeigniter

```
ERROR - 2015-09-16 01:30:08 --> 404 Page Not Found: 
ERROR - 2015-09-16 01:30:29 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
ERROR - 2015-09-16 01:30:30 --> 404 Page Not Found: 
ERROR - 2015-09-16 01:31:30 --> Could not find the language line "form_validation_verifylogin"
ERROR - 2015-09-16 01:31:30 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
```

These are my application/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
```

Bellow is my application/config/routes.php setting

```
 $route['Frontend/album_photos/(:num)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'Frontend/album_photos/index/$1/$2/$3';
    $route['Frontend/album_photos/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'Frontend/album_photos/index/$1/$2';
    $route['Frontend/news_detail/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'Frontend/news_detail/index/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Frontend/index/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'Frontend/index/$i';
$route['default_controller'] = 'Frontend/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['Frontend/download_documents'] = 'Frontend/download_documents/$1';



//these routes works for admin panel
$route['Users/index'] = 'Users/index';
$route['Users/validate_login'] = 'Users/validate_login';
$route['Users/logout'] = 'Users/logout';

$route['Dashboard/index'] ='Dashboard/index';

$route['Aps_pages/manage'] ='Aps_pages/manage';
$route['Aps_pages/create'] ='Aps_pages/create';
$route['Aps_pages/submit'] ='Aps_pages/submit';
$route['Aps_pages/delete'] ='Aps_pages/delete';


$route['Aps_news/manage'] ='Aps_news/manage';
$route['Aps_news/create'] ='Aps_news/create';
$route['Aps_news/submit'] ='Aps_news/submit';
$route['Aps_news/delete'] ='Aps_news/delete';



$route['Aps_events/manage'] ='Aps_events/manage';
$route['Aps_events/create'] ='Aps_events/create';
$route['Aps_events/submit'] ='Aps_events/submit';
$route['Aps_events/delete'] ='Aps_events/delete';

$route['Document_upload/manage'] ='Document_upload/manage';
$route['Document_upload/create'] ='Document_upload/create';
$route['Document_upload/submit'] ='Document_upload/submit';
$route['Document_upload/delete'] ='Document_upload/delete';

$route['Aps_image_slider/manage'] ='Aps_image_slider/manage';
$route['Aps_image_slider/create'] ='Aps_image_slider/create';
$route['Aps_image_slider/submit'] ='Aps_image_slider/submit';
$route['Aps_image_slider/delete'] ='Aps_image_slider/delete';

$route['Aps_testimonials/manage'] ='Aps_testimonials/manage';
$route['Aps_testimonials/create'] ='Aps_testimonials/create';
$route['Aps_testimonials/submit'] ='Aps_testimonials/submit';
$route['Aps_testimonials/delete'] ='Aps_testimonials/delete';

$route['Aps_album_photo/manage'] ='Aps_album_photo/manage';
$route['Aps_album_photo/create'] ='Aps_album_photo/create';
$route['Aps_album_photo/submit'] ='Aps_album_photo/submit';
$route['Aps_album_photo/delete'] ='Aps_album_photo/delete';
$route['Aps_album_photo/search_result'] ='Aps_album_photo/search_result';

$route['Aps_photo_album/manage'] ='Aps_photo_album/manage';
$route['Aps_photo_album/create'] ='Aps_photo_album/create';
$route['Aps_photo_album/submit'] ='Aps_photo_album/submit';
$route['Aps_photo_album/delete'] ='Aps_photo_album/delete';
```

This is my Home.php Controller in Frontend Modules

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MX_Controller
{
    public $data =array();
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mdl_home');
        $this->load->helper('site_helper');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }
    public function index()
    {

        $slug = (string)$this->uri->segment(1);
        //die($slug.'=is a slug');
        $this->data['page'] = $this->mdl_home->get_pages(trim($slug));
        // Fetch the page data
        if(!empty($this->data['page'])){
            $method = '_' .trim($this->data['page']->ViewTemplate);
            if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
                $this->$method();
            }
            else {
                //die('nothing found method not found');
                log_message('error', 'Could not load template ' . $method .' in file ' . __FILE__ . ' at line ' . __LINE__);
                show_error('Could not load template ' . $method);
            }
            //some config to view out put
            $this->data['view_file'] = $this->data['page']->ViewTemplate;
            $this->data['module_name'] ='Frontend';
            //these variable used for main page layout meta keywords description title
            $this->data['page_title'] = $this->data['page']->Title;
            $this->data['keywords'] = $this->data['page']->Keywords;
            $this->data['description'] = $this->data['page']->Description;
            $this->data['body'] = $this->data['page']->Body;
            //load template module for front end
            $this->load->module('Template');
            $this->template->frontend_layout($this->data);
        }else{
            show_404();
        }

    }
    //home page method
    private function _home_page(){
        $this->data['SliderList'] = $this->mdl_home->get_slider_list();
        $this->data['NewsList'] = $this->mdl_home->get_news_with_limit('aps_news',12,'','','NewsDate DESC');
        $this->data['EventsList'] = $this->mdl_home->get_event_list();
        $this->data['TestimonialList'] = $this->mdl_home->get_testimonial_list();
        $this->data['Documents'] = $this->mdl_home->get_uploaded_documents();

    }
    //this method is for static pages
    private function _static_page(){
    }

    //this method load news page
    private function _news_page(){
        $table = 'aps_news';
        $offset = ($this->uri->segment(2) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(2): 0);
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->mdl_home->total_rows($table);
        $config['per_page']= 20;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
        $config['base_url']= site_url((string)$this->uri->segment(1));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data['paginglinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->data['NewsList'] = $this->mdl_home->get_news_with_limit($table,$config["per_page"], $offset,'NewsDate DESC');

    }
    //this method load contact page
    private function _contact_page(){
    }
    //this method load events page
    private function _events_page(){
        $table = 'aps_events';
        $offset = ($this->uri->segment(2) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(2): 0);
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->mdl_home->total_rows($table);
        $config['per_page']= 20;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
        $config['base_url']= site_url((string)$this->uri->segment(1));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data['paginglinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->data['EventsList'] = $this->mdl_home->get_with_limit($table,$config["per_page"], $offset,'EventDate DESC');
    }
    //this method load photo album page
    private function _album_page(){
        $table = 'aps_photo_album';
        $offset = ($this->uri->segment(2) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(2): 0);
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->mdl_home->total_rows($table);
        $config['per_page']= 12;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);
        $config['base_url']= site_url((string)$this->uri->segment(1));
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data['paginglinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->data['AlbumList'] = $this->mdl_home->get_with_limit($table,$config["per_page"], $offset,'AlbumID DESC');

    }

    public function download_documents($file){

        $this->load->helper('download');
        $path = './assets/uploaded_documents/'.$file;
        force_download($path, NULL);
        redirect(base_url());
    }

}
```

This is my Form Validation Library file

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{

    function run($module = '', $group = ''){
        (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI = &$module;
        return parent::run($group);
    }

}
```

and this is my Users Controller file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Users extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //load financial year
        $this->load->model('mdl_users');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
            redirect('Dashboard');
        }else
        {
            $this->login();
        }
    }
    //this function used to show login form view in template one column layout view
    public function login()
    {
        $data['view_file'] = "loginform";
        $data['module_name'] ='Users';
        $data['page_title'] = 'Login Page';
        $this->load->module('Template');
        $this->template->login_layout($data);
    }
    //after entering the login values login form submit value handled by this function or method
    public function validate_login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div style="color:red;">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password', 'required|callback_verify_login');
        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }

    }
    //this function for callback validation after submit button press
    public function verify_login() {

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        //this method is in model folder/directory which interact with database  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ
        $user = $this->mdl_users->check_login_authentication($username, $password);
        if(empty($user)){
            $this->form_validation->set_message('verify_login', 'Sorry the details you provided have not been found');
            return FALSE;
        }else{
            //set user data in session and redirect to dashboard
            $data = array(
                'username'  =>$user->UserName,
                'userid' => $user->UserID,
                'logged_in' => TRUE
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('Dashboard');
        }
    }
    //logout function
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Users');
    }


}
```

Comment: Sir I have same name for my module and controller

Comment: live site link is www.apsjind.in/Users/index please check username admin password admin

Comment: Can you show code of Users.php file

Comment: ok I will show you my code, I think I have problem with my routes

Comment: Change `$route['Users/index'] = 'Users/index';
$route['Users/validate_login'] = 'Users/validate_login';
$route['Users/logout'] = 'Users/logout';` to  `$route['Users/(:any)'] = 'Users/$1';` and check it works or not

Comment: @Rammeshsharma have you changes it?

Comment: I have remove my all routes and set  only these :-  $route['Users/(:any)'] = 'Users/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'Users';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE; but nothing happen

Comment: my live site url is www.apsjind.in/Users check it plz username admin password admin

Comment: ERROR - 2015-09-16 05:48:16 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
ERROR - 2015-09-16 05:48:21 --> Could not find the language line "form_validation_verifylogin"
ERROR - 2015-09-16 05:48:21 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index in my log file

Comment: Keval Rathi I have changed it but nothing happen same problem Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Password.(verifylogin)

Comment: I am working on a different project in codeigniter 3 HMVC school management Keval Rathi will you join me for that project some modules are pending

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89766/discussion-between-keval-rathi-and-rammehar-sharma).

Comment: @RammeshSharma can you continue on chat.